# Is it possible to give a multiplicative law to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ other than the usual multiplicative law to make a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I would like to know for the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (with the group law being addition), is it possible to give a multiplicative law to the group other than the usual multiplicative law to make it a ring?

Comment: Just define all products to be $0$. If that does not answer the question you mean to ask, [edit] to tell us just what properties you require of your new multiplication law, and your efforts to answer this proper question.

Comment: If $p\gt2$ the additive group $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ has nontrivial automorphisms. Given such an automorphism, you can define a new multiplication which makes it a ring isomorphism. Is that what you wanted, or did you want a nonisomorphic ring?

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  Assuming you want the element $1$ to be the multiplicative identity, ordinary multiplication is the only multiplication that makes $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ into a ring because everything is a sum of $1$ enough times, so multiplication by anything is determined once you know multiplication by $1$.

Even if you want to do something weird and not require $1$ to be the multiplicative identity, as long as you want there to be a multiplicative identity you still only get one choice up to isomorphism: all rings with prime order $p$ are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: The OP didn't say that $p$ is a prime, or that the new ring has to be a ring with identity.

Comment: @bof In commutative algebra, all rings have a multiplicative identity, so it is quite reasonable to assume such a condition. When someone asks a question about modular arithmetic in the integers and writes "$p$", it is also reasonable to assume $p$ is meant to be prime.  But actually all that I wrote still works when $p$ is composite: the integers mod $m$ are additively generated by 1, so as soon as we say 1 is going to be a multiplicative identity, multiplication by every integer mod $m$ is determined.